# SQS lambda Missing Required Parameter Missing required key

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Having issues passing message data with Lambda dispatcher SQS, any suggestions

this is the error message

```
* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'DataType' in params.MessageAttributes['message_class']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'stringValue' found in params.MessageAttributes['message_class']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'stringListValues' found in params.MessageAttributes['message_class']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'binaryListValues' found in params.MessageAttributes['message_class']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'dataType' found in params.MessageAttributes['message_class']
* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'DataType' in params.MessageAttributes['timestamp']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'stringValue' found in params.MessageAttributes['timestamp']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'stringListValues' found in params.MessageAttributes['timestamp']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'binaryListValues' found in params.MessageAttributes['timestamp']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'dataType' found in params.MessageAttributes['timestamp']
    at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:40:28)
    at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:132:42)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at callNextListener (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:86:9
    at finish (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:386:7)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:404:9
    at EnvironmentCredentials.get (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:127:7)
    at getAsyncCredentials (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:398:24)
    at Config.getCredentials (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:418:9) {
  code: 'MultipleValidationErrors',
```

PHP code below has the message payload data being sent:

```
/**
     * @param $message
     * @param $options
     * @param int|null $batchNumber
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function generateSqsMessage($message, $options, $batchNumber = null): array
    {
        if (is_object($message)) {
            $message = $message->toArray();
        }


        // By default, don't group messages in the FIFO queue, allow multiple consumer streams unless a Message specifies
        $groupId = $message['group_id'] ?? rand();
        $deduplicateId = md5(json_encode($message['message']) . (string)$message['timestamp']);

        $sqsMessage = [
            'MessageAttributes' => [
                'message_class' => [
                    'DataType' => "String",
                    'StringValue' => $message['message_class']
                ],
                'timestamp' => [
                    'DataType' => "String",
                    'StringValue' => $message['timestamp']
                ]
            ],
            'MessageBody' => json_encode($message['message']),
            'MessageGroupId' => $groupId,
            'MessageDeduplicationId' => $deduplicateId
        ];

        if ($batchNumber) {
            $sqsMessage['Id'] = $batchNumber;
        }

        $sqsMessage = array_merge($options, $sqsMessage);

        return $sqsMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Send a message to a queue
     *
     * @param string $queueName The name of the queue to send messages to
     * @param string|MessageInterface $message The message to send (can be a string, but preference is to send a MessageInterface)
     * @param array $options Any options to send to the driver
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function send($queueName, $message, $options = [])
    {
        $queueUrl = $this->prepare($queueName);

        if (is_string($message)) {
            $decoded = json_decode($message, true);
            $message = $this->reconstructMessageClass($decoded);
        }

        $sqsMessage = $this->generateSqsMessage($message, $options);
        $sqsMessage['QueueUrl'] = $queueUrl;

        $this->client->sendMessage($sqsMessage);
    }
```

Function has been tested and it's working fine, the issue seems related to datatype of message being sent. I'm unable to figure out why this is the case.

Comment: I think the message is pretty explicit with what is wrong. can you validate the payload you passed in is valid? feel free to post the contents/structure of your payload to this so others can further help you debug

Comment: another thing to add, is you may want to call the DocumentClient for DDB, otherwise you will need to send a payload w/ marshaled data.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code above including the payload function

Comment: main issue seems to be related to function itself when I try to send a message to another Queue in this line sqs.sendMessage(JSON.stringify(message), function (err, data)